# How to calculate number of session(12AM-12AM) in between 2 dates

Tags: php

I need to calculate number of session (12AM-12AM) in between 2 dates.

For Ex

```
$a='12-05-2016 11:30AM'
$b='14-05-2016 9:30PM'
```

the output should be 6

```
12th 11:30AM-11:59AM -->1
12TH 12:00PM-11:59PM -->2
13TH 12:00AM-11:59AM -->3
13TH 12:00PM-11:59PM -->4
14TH 12:00AM-11:59AM -->5
14TH 12:00PM-9:30PM --->6
```

I cant able to find correct logic for that. please help to find the required solution

Comment: You can't *find* it? No, ***you*** must write it. Show us your attempt, then we'll try fix it from there. Otherwise you'll fool yourself in to thinking you're learning programming when in reality you're copying and pasting.

Comment: You question is really unclear to me, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Script47 i don need code i just need logic how it can be done?

Comment: Logic is code, unless you mean pseudo-code?

Comment: @Script47   in which case he may be referring to pseudo-logic as well??? Now, we have the math: `Logic=code`, `pseudo-logic=pseudo-code`   :-)

Answer (score 0):

> You may try out the Function below... to test it, go [here](https://eval.in/621825).

```
<?php

    $a          = '12-05-2016 11:30AM';
    $b          = '14-05-2016 9:30PM';

    function getDatesDiffInSteps($date1, $date2){
        $dateSplit1 = explode(" ", $date1); list($dA, $tA) = $dateSplit1;
        $dt1        = new DateTime($date1);
        $dt2        = new DateTime($date2);
        $baseDateA  = new DateTime($dA);
        $prDate     = new DateTime($date1);
        $i          = 1;
        $iDiff      = ($dt2->getTimestamp() - $dt1->getTimestamp());
        $diff       = $dt2->diff($dt1);
        $d           = $diff->d;
        $h          = $diff->h;
        $arr        = [];
        $prDate->setTime(0, 0, 0);

        if($iDiff > 0){
            // GET THE NEAREST 12 O'CLOCK TO THE START TIME:
            $noon       = date_create_from_format("d-m-Y H:i", "{$dA} 11:59");
            $night      = date_create_from_format("d-m-Y H:i", "{$dA} 23:59");
            if($noon>$dt1){
                $arr[]      = $dt1->format("jS h:iA") . " - " . $noon->format("H:iA") . " -->{$i}";
                $prDate->setTime(12, 0, 0);
            }else if($night>$dt1){
                $arr[]      = $dt1->format("jS h:iA") . " - " . $night->format("H:iA") . " -->{$i}";
                $prDate->setTime(24, 0, 0);
            }

            if($d){
                $h += ($d*24);
            }
            for($hr=0; $hr<=($h); $hr+=12){
                $i++;
                $lDate  = $baseDateA->add(new DateInterval("PT12H"));
                $sDate  = $prDate->add(new DateInterval("PT11H59M59S"));
                if($i < intval($h/12)+2){
                    $arr[]  = $lDate->format("jS h:iA") . " - " . $sDate->format("h:iA") . " -->{$i}";
                }else{
                    $arr[]  = $lDate->format("jS h:iA") . " - " . $dt2->format("h:iA") . " -->{$i}";
                }
            }

        }
        return $arr;
    }
    var_dump(getDatesDiffInSteps($a, $b));

    // PRODUCES:
    array (size=6)
      0 => string '12th 11:30AM - 11:59AM -->1' (length=27)
      1 => string '12th 12:00PM - 11:59PM -->2' (length=27)
      2 => string '13th 12:00AM - 11:59AM -->3' (length=27)
      3 => string '13th 12:00PM - 11:59PM -->4' (length=27)
      4 => string '14th 12:00AM - 11:59AM -->5' (length=27)
      5 => string '14th 12:00PM - 09:30PM -->6' (length=27)
```